Poincare recurrence on cylinder sets
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Let $X = \{0,1\}$ with the measure $\mu\{0\} = \mu\{1\} = 1/2$. Consider the sequence space
$$
  \tilde X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N }= \{\mathbf x = (x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n, \dots) \ | \ x_n = 0 \text{ or } 1, \text{ for each } n \}
 $$
Take $\Sigma$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all $\textbf{cylinder sets}$
$$
 C(n,A) = \{\mathbf x \ | \ x_n \in A, A \subset \{0,1\}\}
$$
that is, those sequences whose $n^{th}$ term belongs to some subset $A$ of $\{0,1\}$.
Let $\tilde \mu$ be the measure so that, given a finite collection $A_1, \dots, A_n \subset \{0,1\}$, we have
$$
 \tilde \mu(\{\mathbf x \ | \ x_i \in A_i, i = 1, \dots, n\}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i)
$$
This is called the $\textbf{Bernoulli measure}$ on $\tilde X$. Let $T: \tilde X \to \tilde X$ be the shift map, defined by
$$
 T(x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots) = (x_1, x_2, \dots)
$$
a- Prove that $\mu$ is $T$-invariant.
b-Use Poincare recurrence to prove that almost every sequence in $\tilde X$ has the number 0 appear infinitely often. (Hint: cleverly choose a set $C \subset \tilde X$ to recur to.)
For part (a), I am trying to figure it out.
For part (b) I need some hints please on how to choose this set $C$ please. Could someone clarify this to me please?

An idea for part (b): Set $C=\tilde{X}  \setminus\{(1)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}\}$. Note that $\tilde{\mu}(\{(1)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}\})=0$, so $\tilde{\mu}(C)=1$.
So $C \in \Sigma$ and  Poincare's recurrence theorem yields
$$
\tilde{\mu}(\{x \in C: ~ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall n\ge n_0: T^{(n)}(x) \notin C\})=0.
$$
Hence
$$
\tilde{\mu}(\{x \in C: ~ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \exists n\ge n_0: T^{(n)}(x) \in C\})=1,
$$
and $T^{(n)}(x)=(x_n,x_{n+1},\dots) \in C$ means that the sequence $x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ has an entry $0$ for an index $\ge n$.

For (a) you have to prove that $T$ is $\mu$-measure preserving, that is $\tilde{\mu}(T^{-1}(E))=\tilde{\mu}(E)$ for each $E \in \Sigma$. If I remember right it is sufficient to check this for a generating system of $\Sigma$, this would mean here to check it for each cylinder set.

How can I do that, some links said via direct computation but I can not see it.

If $C=A_1\times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n\times X \times X\times\dots$ is a cylinder then $T^{-1}(C)=X\times A_1\times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n\times X \times X\times\dots$ is also a cylinder with the same measure $\prod_{k=1}^n \mu(A_k)$.

what is $\mathbb N_0$?

$\tilde{\mu}({(1)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}})=0$

why you are writing a cylinder set like this? What are your capital X's?

My capital $X$ is your capital $X$. An element of $C$ is a sequence $(x_k){k=0}^\infty$ with $x{k-1} \in A_k$ $(k=1, \dots,n)$ and $x_{k-1} \in X$ $(k > n)$. It's just an infinite cartesian product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

$\mathbb{N}_0=\mathbb{N} \cup {0}={1,2,3,\dots} \cup {0}$. Don't tell me that $0 \in\mathbb{N}$. I know that the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ depends on the region of the world where you study math. My $ \mathbb{N}$ is ${1,2,3,\dots}$ and I'm too old to change.

Can you please explain your sets inside $\tilde {\mu}$ above? And how did you apply Poincare recurrence to it?

The first set is just the set from Poincare's recurrence theorem, see Theorem 1 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem The second set is the complement of this set up to the complement of $C$ which contains only the sequence $(1)$. Here it is used that $\tilde{\mu}({(1)})=0$,

is not $\tilde {\mu}$ is just the product of $\mu$ and $\mu {1} = 1/2$ by the given? Oh I see it is the limit of $1/2^n$ as $n \to \infty$

How do you know that the complement of $C$ contains only the sequence of all entries 1?

is this $C=\tilde{X}  \setminus{(1)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}}$  an equivalent definition of the definition of the cylinder set given in the problem? If so, why?

is not PR applicable only for finite spaces?

Your measure space is finite: $\tilde{\mu}(\tilde{X})=1$.
